# Custom editable page templates using asp.net web page runtime

Tags: html, asp.net, controls

How to create custom page template from a asp.net web page. I have to make the page generic to make it flexible in creating different styles of templates.(kind of creating my own tables with required columns according to the requirement using drag and drop from any user control)

Thanks

Comment: this is to global... you have to show what you already have, what kind of issue you are struggling with, ...

Comment: I want to create custom editable page html elements from UI by drag and drop